# Php CodeIgniter query syntax

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Helo guys

Iam trying to execute query in `codeigniter`, this one works

```
$this->db->where("DATEDIFF(NOW(), date_and_time) BETWEEN 30 AND 60");
```

But this shows error my controller doesn't load, what i am wrong?

```
$this->db->where("DATEDIFF(NOW(), date_and_time) BETWEEN" .$number1. "AND".$number2.")";
```

Thanking you in advance.

Comment: Crysis could you show more code to understand your problem..

Comment: Iam trying to replace $number1 and $number2 variables instead of 30 and 60.

Comment: what error is it showing?

Comment: i cant fetch the error but my page doesnt load, if i comment that line it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TRY this :

```
$this->db->where( "DATEDIFF (NOW(), date_and_time) BETWEEN ".$number1. " AND ".$number2." ",null, false);
```

Answer (score 2):

You missed the space before and after the "AND":

```
$this->db->where("DATEDIFF(NOW(), date_and_time) BETWEEN " .$number1. " AND ".$number2.")";
```

Comment: $number1 and $number2 should be in proper mysql date format y-m-d

Comment: @saurabh2836: I don't think so as ´DATEDIFF´ returns the number of days between two dates in MySQL.

Answer (score 2):

Here my code :

I just make a query as on my own codeigniter project as following code:

```
$this->db->select();
$this->db->where("DATEDIFF(NOW(), dateCreated) BETWEEN 0 AND 10");
$this->db->get(tb_publishers);
```

Returned query by codeigniter function last_query() as :

```
SELECT * FROM (`tb_publishers`) WHERE DATEDIFF(NOW(), dateCreated) BETWEEN 0 AND 10
```

My output on phpmyadmin as follow

[image]

I hope error may occur due to no space around AND statement please correct that one...

Answer (score 0):

I just modified your code... Try this.

```
$where=array(
              'DATEDIFF(NOW(), date_and_time) BETWEEN'=>$number1,
              'DATEDIFF(NOW(), date_and_time) BETWEEN'=>$number2
           );
$this->db->where($where);
```

Comment: will try and say thk u

Answer (score -1):

Finally this one works

```
 $where=array("DATEDIFF(NOW(), date_and_time) BETWEEN $number1  AND  $number2");                         

  $this->db->where($where);
```

Thanks for the help and suggestion guys

Comment: If this works then the answer above should also work 100% just as fine. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32645738/php-code-igniter-query-syntax#